# Getting Time Duration

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, time

I have a table like below: I want to get time duration for each record which SPEED is greater than 100. I written  a function for that, it’s working fine , but my problem was i have millions of records these table so while i am calling these function from a stored procedure it is taking too much time.

Can you please suggest any other option for this..

Here is my table structure and data

```
---------------------------------------
ID            SPEED          TRACKTIME
---------------------------------------
1              50        2014-10-01 00:20:00
2              80        2014-10-01 00:21:00
3              110       2014-10-01 00:21:30
4              105       2014-10-01 00:22:10
5              97        2014-10-01 00:23:00
6              65        2014-10-01 00:25:00
7              107       2014-10-01 00:26:00
8              101       2014-10-01 00:27:00
9              41        2014-10-01 00:29:00
10             70        2014-10-01 00:30:00
-------------------------------------
```

My function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetOverspeedMinute]
(
    @vehicleID      INT,
    @starttime      DATETIME,
    @endtime        DATETIME,
    @speedlimit     DECIMAL(18, 2)
)
RETURNS @tmp_overspeed TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), TimeInMinute INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tmp_tracking TABLE (
                ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
                TrackingID INT,
                Speed DECIMAL(18, 2),
                TrackTime DATETIME
            )

    INSERT INTO @tmp_tracking
      (
        TrackingID,
        Speed,
        TrackTime
      )
    SELECT Tracking.ID,
           Speed,
           TrackTime
    FROM   Tracking WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE  VehicleID = @vehicleID
           AND TrackTime BETWEEN @starttime AND @endtime

    ;WITH cte_speed AS (
        SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TrackTime),
               *
        FROM   @tmp_tracking
    )    

    INSERT INTO @tmp_overspeed
      (
        TimeInMinute
      )
    SELECT SUM(
               DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [Current Row].TrackTime, [Next Row].TrackTime)
           )
    FROM   cte_speed [Current Row]
           LEFT JOIN cte_speed [Next Row]
                ON  [Next Row].RN = [Current Row].RN + 1
    WHERE  [Current Row].Speed > @speedlimit

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Is this SQL Server? It looks like SQL Server, but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008R2.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2008R2 my advice is to retag the question so it gets answers for that particular version. Maybe some solution could apply just to 2012 or above for example.

Comment: A SQL2012+ specific answer like mine... I didn't see this update until finishing that. Update the tags and add the other details mentioned a the top of my response to the question text, and I'll think about a SQL2008 compatible version later if no one else does first.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what DB you are using, but that syntax looks like MS SQL Server.

Also you do not properly state the table structure - the function refers to VehicleID which doesn't appear in you sample data and you don't say what the data types or what indexes and keys are present. All of this could be significant.

You are pulling a bunch if data into a table variable and processing it there which could be a problem - if there are many rows per vehicle this will hit disk and cause slowness due to that IO.

With SQL Server 2012 or later this is quite easy to do using window functions:

```
SELECT ID, DATEDIFF(MINUTE
            , TrackTime
            , LEAD(TimeTrack) OVER (ORDER BY TimeTrack)
            )
FROM Tracking
WHERE VehicleID = @VehicleID
AND TrackTime BETWEEN @starttime AND @endtime
AND Speed > @speedlimit
ORDER BY TimeTrack
```

For this to be efficient you'll at very least need an index covering VehicleID. Better still either one covering VehicleID & TrackTime (perhaps including speed & ID), or have VehicleID & TrackTime be your clustered index (though for a definite recommendation we need to know a lot more about the other queries the table sees: picking your clustered index to optimise this query might show others).

I'd your indexes are right this should pass over the data once, with and index seek rather than a scan (or worse, a table scan) and no spooling to disk unless the data per vehicle is really massive.

If you want results for multiple vehicles then you need to tell the lead function to split by VehicleID so it becomes `LEAD(TimeTrack) OVER (PARTITION BY VehicleID ORDER BY TimeTrack)`, and add VehicleID to the main ordering clause too.

Comment: He does say in the comments this is 2008R2

Comment: @Mark: Ah, that wasn't there when I first loaded the page and started typing. Will add pre-2012 notes later, my visitors are close to arriving now. The query with `LEAD()` should probably stay too as it may be useful to other passers-by.